# After setting url with window.pushState, how to access that specific link?

Tags: javascript, html

This might just be because I'm not entirely sure how to word it properly, but here's an overview of the problem.

I have a site where it pulls the main content using ajax, and by using pushState, I change the url. Say from "site.com/" to "site.com/area". But reloading this page (or entering it in the url) causes it to completely fail (because there's no such thing as site.com/area).

Is there a way to load the page from that link?

Note, that this isn't about the history / back and forward buttons. I simply want it to load a page from that kind of link.

Comment: So, you want to load "site.com/area", even though it doesn't exist?

Comment: More or less. Do I still have to create a facsimile site.com/area to redirect from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page must exist in one way or another. Depending on what server you're running it on you can redirect all requests to your first page if you want to solve it like that. Then you don't have to create a new page for all "routes", but can build it into your first page/application.

But the page must exist in one way or another.